# Trying to get the data from google DFA reporting tool?

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-dfp

I am trying to get the oauth from Google, After authentication every time I need to copy and paste the Code Generated in my console !
I want that to be automate it ?
Any idea how can I do that ?

I have this code !

`DFA_USER_PROFILE_NAME='MYPROFILE_NAME'`

`scope =
["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting"]`

```
try:

   redirect_uri=redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
   flow=flow_from_clientsecrets('Location of the json file', scope, redirect_uri, message)
   authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
   self.redirect(authorize_url)
   credential = flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)
   storage=StorageByKeyName(credentials,user.user_id(),'credentials'
                         )
   storage.put(credentials)
   user=user.get_current_user()

   credentials = client.oauth2credentials
   client.oauth2credentials = credentials
   http = httplib2.Http()
```

`except BaseException as e:
    print "this is really a error that has occured ",e`

I am trying But i have no clue where I am going wrong ?

what is self.params ?
Is this service free in Google Cloud ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - it should prompt you the first time, but then write the credentials to disk and read them in for subsequent invocations:

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow, argparser
from apiclient.discovery import build

storage = Storage("/path/to/saved_user_creds.dat")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run_flow(flow_from_clientsecrets("/path/to/client_secrets.json", scope=["scope1" ,"scope2"]), storage, argparser.parse_args([]))
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

# Use the http object as needed...
service = build("bigquery", "v1")
result = service.object().method(name=value).execute(http=http)
```

Comment: We have a method **PUT** how can we use that code over here ?
to store the Credentials And use the **GET** method.
How to create .dat file ? in this case ?

Comment: The .dat file is automatically created for you the first time it runs.  Feel free to ignore the last 2 lines, and just use the http object as is, that should work for for GET and PUT requests.